# Change text color to specific color depending on background color

Tags: html, css

I want to have my white text change into a grey that i have selected (#21262A) once it goes over a green SVG that i have, i achieved a similar effect with `mix-blend-mode: difference;` but was unable to get the text color to be a specific color, it would only be the inverse of the background green color on the SVG.

how would I achieve this effect?

**Before**

[image]

**mix-blend-mode: difference**

[image]

i want the text to be the same color as the background above it

Comment: Can you reproduce your question with a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
mix-blend-mode: overlay;
```

Comment: this doesn't result in the text being #21262A, it turn the text transparent